# Format a paragraph to new section

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm sorry if my question title is not clear, because I don't which technique to be called in my situation.

I have a layout like below image. In `1.2` I have `1.3.1` `1.3.2` and `1.3.3`
[image]

But in my document, I have `1.3.4` as below image:
[image]

So my question is: How can I make this section appear in the list, same level with others such as `1.3.2` `1.3.3` ...

Answer (score -1):

this works for me:

1. highlight entire line 1.3.3 (or any other line that works correctly)
2. click format paintbrush
3. apply the format to the entire line 1.3.4 (by left-clicking in its margin)